# "Replace John with Andrew" which of this name is to be trashed

Tags: meaning, grammar

Greeting to all in this room,

Please help with this statement.

"Replace John with Andrew" which one becomes trashed among John and Andrew?

Comment: Replace A with B and Substitute B for A are very important idioms. Any dictionary will tell you the difference. Good luck.

Comment: I assume you are referring to editing a document. Every occurrence of the word "John" would be replaced with "Andrew", so "John" would be trashed.

Answer (score -1):

John is trashed.

[Replace](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/replace)

> to take the place of something, or to put something or someone in the place of something or someone else:
>
> The factory ***replaced most of its workers with robots.***